# Render characters in buffer differently, e. g. render backslash as lambda

Tags: conceal

Is it possible to render single characters as a different character in nvim, i.e. "replace" them visually in the buffer?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you give an example of which specific characters you'd like to replace? It would be much easier to give you specific advice for your exact use case. Or to infer a better way to do it based on what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the conceal feature:
You define a [syntax match](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-match) with a regex pattern that captures the desired text (a single character in your case) and specifies a concealing character in the `cchar` option. Then you set a [conceallevel](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27conceallevel%27), which either hides text that matches a syntax pattern or masks it with one specific character (except for the line you're currently on – look into [concealcursor](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27concealcursor%27) to change this).

For instance, to replace all occurrences of `/` with `X`, you'd use the following commands:

```
:syntax match ReplaceSlashWithX "/" conceal cchar=X
:set conceallevel=2
```

The concealed text is highlighted. To remove the highlighting, you need to edit the [highlight group](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#highlight-groups) `Conceal`:

```
:highlight Conceal ctermbg=none ctermfg=none guibg=none guifg=none
```

Comment: I would rather recommend to use the `matchadd()` functionality, which does not depend on syntax highlighting

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt That's probably worth posting your own answer explaining how to use `matchadd()` to implement this feature.